$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b(k) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|b(k)-a(n,k)| $
Let
$a:\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}\ \ , \ b:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} ,\ ; \ a(n,k)\geq0, \ b(k) \geq0 \ \forall n,k \in \mathbb{N} 
$.
Assume that
$\displaystyle  
\lim_{n \to \infty} a(n,k)=0 \ \forall k \in \mathbb{N}
$.
Then, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} b(k) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|b(k)-a(n,k)| 
$ holds?
I expect this equation to hold true, but I haven't been able to prove it.
Any advise would be appreciated.

You are looking for Fatou's lemma.
Set $f_n(k) = |b(k)-a(n,k)|$ then from the lemma it follows that
$$ \liminf_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|b(k)-a(n,k)| \ge  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \liminf_{n \to \infty}|b(k)-a(n,k)|$$
The results follows due to $$\liminf_{n \to \infty}|b(k)-a(n,k)| = |b(k) - 0| = |b(k)| = b(k)$$.
